# Unit testing with MockitoJunitRunner: thenReturn always returns null for any(...) matchers

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4

Using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE. In an unit test with MockitoJunitRunner, I'm mocking a REST controller as follows:

```
  @Mock
  private MyController myController;
```

Then, I'm defining the expectations of the endpoint call as follows:

```
when (myController.myEndpoint(any(MyInputDto.class), any(OAuth2Authentication.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<MyOutputDto>(myOutputDto, HttpStatus.OK));
```

But the following call:

```
ResponseEntity<MyOutputDto> resp = myController.myEndpoint(any(MyInputDto.class), any(OAuth2Authentication.class));
assertNotNull(resp);
```

raises java.lang.AssertionError as resp is null. Why is that ? Of course, the two parameters are different instances between the when(...) clause and the call (probably both null), but my understanding is that they don't have to match as I'm using any(...) matcher, meaning that whatever these instances are, the return should be the same.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Why are you calling the endpoint with matchers? You should be creating a `MyInputDto` and authentication (or mock them) and pass those, not use matchers.

Comment: @M.Deinum: because that's a perfect legal thing to do and there is no reason not to do it. And also because the OAuth2Authentication object cannot neither be instantiated nore mocked.

Comment: It isn't. Those are matchers not objects. Why wouldn't you be able to mock `OAuth2Authentication`. That is perfectly doable with `Mockito.mock(your-class-here>);`

Comment: As @M.Deinum already said, you should't use matchers when calling a mocked object. Use actual objects instead: an instance of MyInputDto and OAuth2Authetication. But all that would do is testing if your mock works, not if your method call works on the object to be tested. You probably don't want to mock your controller, but the other objects as M. Deinum wrote. (Not posted as answer for now bc not sure what you want to do here.)

Comment: The `any` Mathers behave exactly as they should. The problem is you are also using matchers in calling the actual method THAT is something you shouldn't be doing. As @ModusTollens is also correctly observing is that your test is actually testing nothing, it tests a mock not the controller. If you want to test your controller you should mock its dependencies NOT the controller itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum: "The problem is you are also using matchers in calling the actual method THAT is something you shouldn't be doing." My understanding is that if I shouldn't do it, then I shouldn't be able to do it. But I'm able to do it and, then, why shouldn't I do it ? Could you please explain what exactly happens when I do it ? What are the values of the arguments which are passed when using matchers instead of values ? Once again, this is perfectly correct because allowed.

Comment: The answer from @ModusTollens explains all of it. It is about matchers, they are for matching not mocking!. So you register behavior saying any instance of `MyInputDto` is ok. But you aren't calling it with an instance of `MyInputDto` but with another matcher. Hence it doesn't match and leads to the default behavior of the mocking framework to return `null`in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your mocked object to return a new `ResponseEntity` when its `myEndpoint` method is called with two parameters: any object of type `MyInputDto` and any object of type `OAuth2Authentication`.

But when you actually call the method using

```
ResponseEntity<MyOutputDto> resp = myController.myEndpoint(any(MyInputDto.class), any(OAuth2Authentication.class));
```

you *don't* call it with objects of those types, but with `any` matchers. That case wasn't mocked, and it certainly wasn't your intention to mock matcher arguments.

Calling with actual objects instead, like

```
ResponseEntity<MyOutputDto> resp = myController.myEndpoint(new MyInputDto(), new OAuth2Authentication());
```

would work, **but that would not provide what you want to achieve by running a mocked test**: it would just check if the mock returns what you defined, but it would't test your controller behaviour.

---

What you should do instead:

**Don't mock the class you want to test; mock its dependencies.**

```
private MyController myController;

@Mock
private MyInputDto inputDto;
@Mock
private OAuth2Authentication authentication;

// mock all method calls that are needed on dependencies
when(inputDto.someMethod(...)).thenReturn(...);
[...]
when(authentication.someMethod(...)).thenReturn(...);
[...]
```

Now you can test the actual behaviour of your test object:

```
ResponseEntity<MyOutputDto> resp = myController.myEnpoint(inputDto, authentication);
assertNotNull(resp);
```

A nice Mockito tutorial: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

---

Mockito even *hints* at something being wrong when trying to implement the test like you did in your question. Running your test I get

> [MockitoHint] MockitoTest.test (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
>
> [MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at MockitoTest.test(MockitoTest.java:24)
>
> [MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at MockitoTest.test(MockitoTest.java:26)

Line 24 refers to the line where the mock was stubbed (the *when(...).thenReturn()* part) because it is never used; line 26 referes to the calling line because it uses Matchers instead of objects.

You should see a similar output on your console when running the test.

Comment: @Modius Tollens: Thanks for the complete answer. But what happens when I call using matchers ? Shouldn't it manage to make the call with whatever arguments since I'm saying any(...) and, consequently, I don't care ?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, generally speaking it is possible to use any argument. But the arguments _must_ match the definition. When you define the argument as _any()_, any object can be used. But you defined it as _any(MyInputDto.class)_ (which is correct, but it means the argument _must_ be an object of type MyInputDto). But you later _called_ with _any(...)_, which is an object of type Matcher, not an object of type MyInputDto.

Comment: okay I undrestand now, thanks. I would have expected to get an exception in this case where the arguments don't match but that's fine. And thanks also for the tutos which seems good. Are there any published books on Moskito ?

Comment: @Nicolas Glad to be able to help :). Unfortunately I don't know any Mockito books, but I am sure they exist!